# Get specific row in repeater with specific value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using an [Advanced Custom Fields repeater field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) that has two fields for each row - `image` and `main_image`.

If `main_image` in a row has "Yes" selected then I want it to output the `image` from that row. If "Yes" isn't selected for any rows then I just want it to select the first `image`.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php if( have_rows( 'gallery' ) ): ?>
  <?php $rowcounter = 1;
  while( have_rows( 'gallery' ) ): the_row(); ?>
    <?php $image = get_sub_field( 'image' ); ?>

    <?php if(get_sub_field('main_image') == "Yes") { ?>

      <a href="#" class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $image[$rowcounter]['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image[$rowcounter]['alt']; ?>">
      </a>

    <?php } else { ?>

      <a href="#" class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $image[1]['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image[1]['alt']; ?>">
      </a>  

    <?php } ?>  


  <?php $rowcounter++;
  endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I thought by doing this `<?php echo $image[$rowcounter]['url']; ?>` it would output the image from that row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the first row then run the loop to change the featured image value conditionally.

```
<?php 

if( have_rows( 'gallery' ) ) 
{
    // Load the first row and set the featured image
    the_row();

    $featured_image = get_sub_field( 'image' );

    while( have_rows( 'gallery' ) )
    { 
        the_row();

        // If a different image was set to be featured, set it and break out of loop
        if( get_sub_field('main_image') == "Yes" ) 
        {
            $featured_image = get_sub_field( 'image' );
            break;
        }
    }
?>
    <a href="#" class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $featured_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $featured_image['alt']; ?>">
    </a>  
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$image` var is reset in every `while` - iteration in this line: `<?php $image = get_sub_field( 'image' ); ?>`. Also, you don't have to close the php - tags just to open them again on the next line, it just makes the code harder to read.

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'gallery' ) ) :

$images = [];
$i = 0;

while ( have_rows( 'gallery' ) ): the_row();

    $images[ $i ] = get_sub_field( 'image' );

    if ( get_sub_field( 'main_image' ) == "Yes" ) { ?>

        <a href="#" class="slide">
            <img src="<?php echo $images[ $i ][ 'url' ]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[ $i ][ 'alt' ]; ?>">
        </a>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <a href="#" class="slide">
            <img src="<?php echo $images[ 0 ][ 'url' ]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[ 0 ][ 'alt' ]; ?>">
        </a>

    <?php }

    ++$i;

endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I seem to have `<img src="" alt="">` output for the images?

Comment: I don't now the slugs for your repeater fields, so I assumed `url` and `alt`.

Comment: Do you use an 'image' type field in your repeater or do you create each image attribute in a seperate field, like 'Url'?

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear, I use the image field type... not separate fields

Comment: Do you have it set to return an image object?

Comment: Yes it's an image object

Comment: And you have another row with the slug `main_image`? I'll update my code.

Comment: I've just added an image to the question - so it's a repeater field, with two fields within, the image field is set to the image field type and is set as an object. The main image field is a dropdown with yes/no.

Comment: Updated my answer. I tested this locally and it only shows an image if "main_image" was set to "Yes", otherwise the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the rows:

```
$rows = get_field('repeater' );
```

0 will get the first row, remember that the count starts at 0:

```
$specific_row = $rows[YOUR_ROW_NUMBER];
```

Get the sub field value:

```
$sub_field_value = $specific_row['SUB_FIELD_NAME'];
```

Comment: `$rows = get_field('repeater' );'
'$specific_row = $rows[YOUR_ROW_NUMBER]; '
'$sub_field_value = $specific_row['SUB_FIELD_NAME']; '